# What is the difference between these two covariance functions?

Tags: python, function, numpy, jupyter

I want to rewrite this covariance function:

```
 def cov1(a, b):
    a_mean = np.mean(a)
    b_mean = np.mean(b)
    sum = 0
    for i in range(0, a.size):
        sum = ((a[i] - a_mean) * (b[i] - b_mean)) + sum
    return sum/(len(a)-1)
```

I tried re-writing the summation part to make it just be np.sum:

```
def cov(a, b):
    a_mean = np.mean(a)
    b_mean = np.mean(b)
    for i in range(0, a.size):
        summation = np.sum((a[i] - a_mean) * (b[i] - b_mean))
    return summation/(len(a)-1)
```

but when I take two arrays:

```
a = np.arange(1,11,1)
b = np.arange(10,21,1)
```

and I try the two different functions, I get different answers. The function cov1 is the correct one:

```
print(cov1(a,b))
print(cov(a,b))

9.166666666666666
2.0
```

why is this? How do I fix the function cov(a,b) to make it the same as cov1(a,b)?

Comment: Notice that the arrays `a` and `b` have different length. Not sure if that's a typo or not

Comment: `cov1` adds the partial sum from the current step each time; `cov` replaces the old value. Also, don't use `sum` as a variable name, because it hides the built-in `sum` function. Also, you don't have to implement this yourself. Did you try putting `numpy covariance` into a search engine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First I think both your function should ensure the input are the same length.

Second, your function could be this

```
def cov(a, b):
    a_mean = np.mean(a)
    b_mean = np.mean(b)
    return ((a - a_mean) * (b - b_mean)).sum() / (len(a) - 1)
```

Third, numpy has a cov function, just try

```
np.cov(a, b)
```

This will return the covariance matrix of the variables. In your case, you can just use np.cov(a, b)[0, 0]

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to define `summation` in `cov` and you forgot to add `summation` to the new sum.
Try this instead:

```py
def cov(a, b):
    a_mean = np.mean(a)
    b_mean = np.mean(b)
    # Added summation and assigned 0 to it, like for sum in cov1
    summation = 0
    for i in range(0, a.size):
        # Added + summation here, just like in cov1
        summation = np.sum((a[i] - a_mean) * (b[i] - b_mean)) + summation 
    return summation/(len(a)-1)
```